# SpiderMonkey AST javascript manipulation

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, spidermonkey, visitor-pattern

I have SpiderMonkey AST, this is javascript object. I use "Esprima", "Acorn" or other libs to generate AST from javascript file. My AST is specified by Mozilla parser API.

I want to manipulate this AST from javascript - remove/add/edit nodes in it. How to do it safely? 
For example i want to replace all boolean Literal with !1 or !0.

Now i use walker from "Acorn" lib:

```
acornWalk.simple(tree, {
    Literal: function(node, scope) {
        if(typeof node.value === 'boolean'){
            var expressionTrue = {
                    "type": "UnaryExpression",
                    "operator": "!",
                    "prefix": true,
                    "argument": {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "value": 0,
                        "raw": "0"
                    }
                },
                expressionFalse = {
                    "type": "UnaryExpression",
                    "operator": "!",
                    "prefix": true,
                    "argument": {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "value": 1,
                        "raw": "1"
                    }
                },

                replace = function(node, newNode){
                    for(var prop in newNode){
                        node[prop] = newNode[prop];
                    }
                };

            replace(node, node.value ? expressionTrue : expressionFalse);
        }
    }
 });
```

But it seems to be not good practice because the "start", "end" properties in node is not changed and it can break code generated from that AST. Am i right?

Comment: And after you modify the AST, what do you expect to do with it?  Regenerate the source text?  How?

Comment: @IraBaxter: yes, i use "escodegen"